# How to use my custom menus as seperate pages?

Tags: menus

I want my site to have different pages, so basically, I want to make it that when you select a menu, it takes you to a different part of the site.. with different information that I have typed in.. how do I do this?

Example - if you click the ´Contact Us´ menu, I want our contact details to appear, and then if you click on ´Pictures`, our pictures will appear etc..

Thanks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a corresponding ["Page"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) for the items in your menu, unless those items are things that would have an automatically generated page, like a category archive or author archive. You would then select those items when you create the menu.